# Copy a .txt file to excel

Tags: excel, vba, copy, txt

I am trying to copy multiple txt file into excel but having a little issue on the following:

```vb
Sub devise(FICHIER, FEUILLE)
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(FEUILLE)
    Dim wbcopy As Workbook
    ChDir "R:\Oco_R\Valoco"
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="R:\Oco_R\Valoco\" & FICHIER, Origin:= _
        xlWindows, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:= _
        Array(Array(0, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(26, 1), Array(35, 1), Array(46, 1), _
        Array(53, 1), Array(64, 1), Array(72, 1))
    Selection.Copy
    ws.Activate
    ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
    'ActiveSheet.Paste
    ws.Rows("1:4").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ws.Cells.Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:= _
        xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:= _
        xlTopToBottom
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

I already defined the workbook where I would like the txt to be copied to. But I was wondering how I could DIM the txt file so that I can close it? For example `FIHCIER.close`, but doesn't work of course...
In the code I'm using `ActiveWorkbook.Close` but it is referring to my excel file which I don't want to close.
I tried using a `Set wbC` but haven't really succeeded...

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Woudn't [PowerQuery](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-data-from-a-folder-with-multiple-files-power-query-94b8023c-2e66-4f6b-8c78-6a00041c90e4#:~:text=Combine%20and%20Transform%20Data%20To,select%20Combine%20%3E%20Combine%20and%20Load.) be the better approach?

Answer (score 0):

When you open a textfile using `Workbooks.OpenText`, Excel will create a workbook (containing one sheet) from the text file.
For some strange reasons `OpenText` is not implemented as function (in opposite to Workbooks.Open`), so you can't do something like

```
set txtFile = Workbooks.OpenText(MyTextFileName)
```

However, after you open the file, it is automatically the `ActiveWorkbook`, so you can do the following:

```
Dim txtFile as Workbook
Workbooks.OpenText filename:=MyTextFileName 
Set txtFile = ActiveWorkbook
(...)
txtFile.close saveChanges:=False
```